# How to maintain consistent directory scope across large PHP project?

Tags: php, include, directory, directory-structure

I'm a relatively new developer and am tackling my first ever "large" website. I want to have a persistent directory scope throughout my project for ease of development. Here's what I mean:

Say I have a (simplified) directory structured like below:

```
Site Root/
  index.php
  js/
  css/
  img/
  classes/
  includes/
```

if I'm working in `index.php` and want to `include()` a file from `Classes/`, it's easy:

```
include('classes/user.php');
```

but, if I'm deep inside, say, the includes folder and want to include a class, it gets messy:

```
include('../../../classes/user.php');
```

Optimally, I'd like to be able to say `include('classes/user.php');` from within any file.

What measures can I take to make my directory structure as simple to access as possible? I'm thinking of some sort of include I include on every page that stores the root directory relative to the current directory and saves it to a string, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this.

EDIT: not sure why this is marked as "too broad"? I think what I am asking is pretty specific, but please enlighten me if this is not the case..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always try to us the `__DIR__` [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) when using `includes()` and `requires()`, as the lack of it can sometimes cause errors, and it can make finding erroneous scripts a little easier.

As far as calling scripts, you should use constants with root paths. Like so:

```
// Value is something like '/var/www'
define('PATH_BASE', __DIR__, 1);
// Value is '/var/www/system/'
define('PATH_SYS', PATH_BASE.'/system/', 1);
// Value is '/var/www/assets/css/'
define('PATH_CSS', PATH_BASE.'/assets/css/', 1);
// Value is '/var/www/assets/js/'
define('PATH_JS', PATH_BASE.'/assets/js/', 1);

// Will always get '/var/www/system/core.php' no matter where it is called
require (PATH_SYS.'core.php');
```

This is probably the easiest and most effective method, but is far from the only way. Just keep in mind that `__DIR__` uses the basepath of the file it is called from, not the requested file.

So if the requested file was "http://example.com/index.php" (aka '/var/www/index.php'), but `__DIR__` is called in '/var/www/system/core.php'; the value of `__DIR__` would be '/var/www/system'